# I have checkbox that generates a string but need the string to appear on a separate page (separate file)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, checkbox

This is the checkbox that I have in asp.net which generates a string next to it when checked.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="autoDoc" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="autoDoc_Checked" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:Literal ID="StrautoDoc" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal>
```

This is the C# code for the functionality.

```
 protected void autoDoc_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StrautoDoc.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + " - " + GetUser() + " assigned " + txtInstructions.Text + " task to " + GetTaskee();
}
```

This is getting the current date, logged in user, and the person being assigned, from the database.  But all this does right now is posts the string next to the checkbox upon clicking it.  I instead need it to post to a different page (different file) in a specific location.  How would I go about approaching this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use a Session. When the user selects the checkbox store the string value in a Session.

Example:

```
  protected void autoDoc_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var strautoDocText = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + " - " + GetUser() + 
    " assigned " + txtInstructions.Text + " task to " + GetTaskee();
    StrautoDoc.Text = strautoDocText;
    Session["StrautoDoc"] = strautoDocText;
  }
```

You can then access the value of the Session when loading another page.

Example:

`var storedUserAssigned = Session["StrautoDoc"]`

Comment: Would I have to make a new method to put that variable that is holding the session?

Comment: How exactly are you wanting to display the stored value on the other page?

Comment: Just as the generated string inside of a div

Comment: But more specifically inside a table <td>

Comment: Ok yes in that case you will need create another method in order to populate the Text within the Div with the Session value.

Comment: Oh okay. Would I have to put that variable holding the session in a lambda expression or something?  Sorry, I’m fairly new to asp.net c#

Comment: I really really appreciate the help though!